# How do I dectect mobile devices while ignoring IPad

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to ignore IPad as a mobile device in my application

I'm currently using this expression to detect mobile devices:

```
request.user_agent =~ /Mobile|webOS/
```

Standard stuff. The iPad agent string looks something like:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B405 Safari/531.21.10
```

I've tried the following without success:

```
request.user_agent =~ /!(iPad)(Mobile|webOS)/
```

Please let me know what is wrong with the expression.

Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [negative matches](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) or

```
request.user_agent =~ /Mobile|webOS/ && !(request.user_agent =~ /iPad/)
```

Comment: That did it, thank you. I'm new so it won't let me vote it up. I did accept it as the answer. I'd be interested to see this as a single regular expression if possible.